# Continously Publish Matlab Text Output to a Website

Tags: asp.net, matlab, compiler-construction, web

Is there a way I can, in real time, publish my Matlab output to a website.

Let's say for example, I wanted to display the time of the day.  I would set Matlab to run a forloop to add 1 second, every 1 second.  Could I continuously display that output on a website somehow?

Comment: You'll caching because uploading HTML every second means that a lot of people won't see the page.  That will depend on your application, maybe you need a script to update mysql records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Writing to a web site is simply uploading the html file to some specific directory.

So, simply use Matlab's ftp API to upload your file, giving it the dir path on the server where you want the file written/uploaded to.

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ftpclass.html

Create an html file from matlab, write it to disk, and then send it to the server using the above API

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!

Saved me a lot of time tonight,

Thanks again!

Comment: This actually set my alarm bells a-ringing. What happens if someone requests the page while you're halfway through uploading a new version?